# RxJava2 how call in parallel different request

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm Really new on this but What I'm trying to do is

Do two call on parallel both are objects, then I need create a new object using the properties of both

This is a pseudo example that I need

```
OperatorINeed(service.callOne(), service.callTwo())
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .concatMap(new BiFunction<ObjectA, ObjectB, ObjectC>() {
    public ObjectC apply(ObjectA objectA, ObjectB objectB) {
      // do things
      return objectC;
    }
  })
  onErrorResumeNext(...)
```

but I can't find any concrete example of this thing

Comment: zip or combinelatest works for yah?? http://rxmarbles.com/

Answer (score 0):

use `zip()` operator, it will collect both emissions from the two service `Observable`s that will run in parraell, and there you provide the `BiFunction` to map both Objects properties to a new single Object, afterwards you can apply `concatMap()` with `objectC` :

```
Observable.zip(service.callOne(), service.callTwo(),
            new BiFunction<ObjectA, ObjectB, ObjectC>() {
                @Override
                public ObjectC apply(ObjectA objectA, ObjectB objectB) throws Exception {
                    // do things
                    return objectC;
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .concatMap(objectC -> { //create an Observable using objectC})
            .onErrorResumeNext(...)
```